# I face this error - Message: syntax error, unexpected 'return' (T_RETURN), expecting identifier (T_STRING), what was i missed? my code mentioned below

Tags: php, codeigniter

i'm using php language and codeigniter framework,The error which i faced is Message: syntax error, unexpected 'return' (T_RETURN), expecting identifier (T_STRING)
and my code is

```
function return(){
    $data['title'] = "PO Retun List";
    $data['page'] = "purchases/return";
    $this->load->view('index',$data);
}
```

Comment: `return` is already in use as a keyword in the PHP language, so you can not name a function `return`.

Answer (score 0):

**return** is a reserved keyword use another name for your function